# How to enable unit testing on a tightly coupled business\data layers without DI?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm working on a project that is an older 3 tier design, any new functionality added needs to be unit testable.

The problem is the business layer / data layers are tightly coupled like in the sample below.  The BL just news up a data layer object... so it's almost impossible to mock up this way.  We don't have any Dependency Injection implemented so constructor injection isn't possible.  So what is the best way to modify the structure so that the data layer can be mocked up without the use of DI?

```
public class BLLayer()
{

   public GetBLObject(string params)
   {
     using(DLayer dl = new DLayer())
     {  
        DataSet ds = dl.GetData(params);

        BL logic here....

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Dependency Injection implemented so constructor injection isn't possible."? Do you mean that you cannot use constructors in your classes or just that you do not have a DI container/framework?

Comment: @steenhulthin  We don't have a DI framework up and running in the project.

Comment: How is `dl` used in the code later (does the dl.GetData(params) call just retrieves the data into the dl object.)?

Comment: @steenhulthin Yes, I've updated the sample to show that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not ruling out constructor injection *per se*, you just don't have an IOC container set up.  That's fine, you don't need one.  You can do Poor Man's Dependency Injection and still keep constructor injection.

Wrap the DataLayer with an interface, and then create a factory that will make `IDataLayer` objects on command.  Add this as a field to the object you're trying to inject into, replacing all `new` with calls to the factory.  Now you can inject your fakes for testing, like this:

```
interface IDataLayer { ... }
interface IDataLayerFactory 
{
   IDataLayer Create();
}    

public class BLLayer()
{
  private IDataLayerFactory _factory;

   // present a default constructor for your average consumer
  ctor() : this(new RealFactoryImpl()) {} 

  // but also expose an injectable constructor for tests
  ctor(IDataLayerFactory factory)
  { 
    _factory = factory;
  }  

  public GetBLObject(string params)
  {
    using(DLayer dl = _factory.Create())  // replace the "new"
    {  
      //BL logic here....    
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to have a default value of the *actual* factory you want to use in real code.

Comment: Could you please share when did you learn this?

Answer (score 4):

Dependency Injection is just one of many patterns that fall under the umbrella concept known as "Inversion of Control". The main criteria is to provide a "seam" between components so that you can separate In short, there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Dependency Injection itself has several derivates: Constructor Injection (dependencies passed in through the constructor), Property Injection (dependencies represented as read/write properties) and Method Injection (dependencies are passed into the method). These patterns assume that class is "closed for modification" and expose their dependencies for consumers to change. Legacy code is rarely designed this way, and system-wide architectural changes (such as moving to constructor injection and a IoC container) isn't always straight forward.

Other patterns involve decoupling the resolution and/or construction of objects away from the subject under a test. Simple Gang of Four patterns like a Factory can do wonders. A Service Locator is like a global object factory, and while I'm not a huge fan of this pattern, it can be used to decouple dependencies.

In the example that you've outlined above, the test pattern "Subclass to Test" would allow you to introduce seams without system wide re-architecture. In the pattern, you move object creation calls like "new DLayer()" to a virtual method, and then create a subclass of the subject.

Micheal Feather's "Working with Legacy Code" has a catalog of patterns and techniques that you can use to put your legacy code into a state that would allow you to move towards DI.

Answer (score 2):

If `DLayer` is only used in the `GetBLObject` method I would inject a factory in the method call. Something like: (Building on @PaulPhillips example)

```
public GetBLObject(string params, IDataLayerFactory dataLayerFactory)
   {
       using(DLayer dl = dataLayerFactory.Create())  // replace the "new"
       {  
            //BL logic here....    
       }
   }
```

However it seems that what you really want to work with in the Business Layer is a `DataSet`. So another way is to let `GetBLObject` take the `DataSet` in the method call in stead of `string param`. In order to make that work you could create a class that handles just getting the `DataSet` from a `DLayer`. For instance:

```
public class CallingBusinesslayerCode
{
    public void CallingBusinessLayer()
    {
        // It doesn't show from your code what is returned
        // so here I assume that it is void. 
        new BLLayer().GetBLObject(new BreakingDLayerDependency().GetData("param"));
    }
}

public class BreakingDLayerDependency
{
    public DataSet GetData(string param)
    {
        using (DLayer dl = new DLayer()) //you can of course still do ctor injection here in stead of the new DLayer() 
        {
            return dl.GetData(param);
        }
    }
}

public class BLLayer
{
    public void GetBLObject(DataSet ds)
    {
        // Business Logic using ds here.
    }
}
```

One warning: Mocking out `DataSet` (which you have to in both this and Paul Phillips solution) can be really cumbersome, so testing this will be possible, but not necessarily a lot of fun.

Comment: Interesting point about the burdensome nature of creating a fake `DataSet`, I had failed to consider that